# Why does the volume of my sound go down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have a voip app and for an incoming call I redirect to a separate view where the user can accept or reject the call. I want a sound to be played while in this view, so I load a sound file:

```
NSString *ringtoneSoundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ringtone" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *ringtoneSoundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ringtoneSoundPath];
ringtone = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:ringtoneSoundUrl error:nil];
ringtone.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

and then in the viewcontroller where I want the sound to be played I have these methods:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [ringtone play];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [ringtone stop];
}
```

This works, but when the call is finished and I call a second time the volume of the sound is suddenly very low. I checked the device's volume settings, but it's still at max. Why does the volume go down when stopping the sound and then playing it again? It doesn't repeat, so the third time, it's just as low as the second time.

Comment: Use [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0]; while playing sound.

Comment: @ASHISHT This makes the sound not play at all

Answer (score 0):

We had the similar issue. If you have voip app it means that you use `setCategory:` in `AVAudioSession`.
So, you have the code like:

```
AVAudioSession *aSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
if ([aSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil]) {
    [aSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:nil];
    [aSession setActive: YES error:nil];
}
```

But when you use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord the volume becomes low.

So, before rington play you should set e.g.:

```
if ([aSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil]) {
    [aSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:nil];
    [aSession setActive:YES error:nil];
}
```

Hope this helps